# How to use rigitbody2d.AddTorque() in JavaScript? (unity2D)

Tags: unity, 2d, javascript, rotation, rigidbody

I just want to know how to use rigitbody2d.AddTorque() and an example script would be great :D. I am trying to rotate a cube forever using it as a test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that "Is Kinematic" option  for rigidbody in the inspector is off.

Here is a very basic example for adding torque.

```
var torque: float;
var rigidBody: Rigidbody2D;

function Start() {
    torque = 20;
    rigidBody = GetComponent.<Rigidbody2D>();
}


function FixedUpdate() 
{
    rigidBody.AddTorque(Time.deltaTime*torque);
}
```

Time.delta time is just to make it device independent.

Hope this resolves your doubts :)